# How to make numbers not be shown in scientific form?

Tags: php, floating-point-precision

I want to write an array of floating point numbers into files

```
<?php
$x=[0.000455,0.000123,0.00005690330203];
$fname='test.txt';
$str='';
foreach($x as $elem){
$str .= "$elem\n";
  }
file_put_contents($fname,$str);
?>
```

but in the test.txt, I see

```
0.000455
0.000123
5.690330203E-5
```

I don't want the float point number to be shown in scientific/exponential form, I hope they keep the original form, 
besides, there are also large integers like 12430120340
so if I use special format for floating point numbers, like 0.000123293304
then maybe it is not suitable for large integers, maybe convert them into strings could be a good idea? but how?

Comment: what do you mean by original form? give an example.

Comment: In this instance, he/she means: '0.00005690330203' instead of '5.690330203E-5'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `number_format` function to set a precision:

**Example**:

```
$mynum = 24.2837162893;
$mynum = number_format($mynum, 2);
echo($mynum);

// Outputs 24.28
```

So if you decide you want all your numbers to have 10 decimal places, you would just use `$mynum = number_format($mynum, 10);`.

Also, see the [sprintf()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) function for other formatting options.

**[EDIT]**

In your particular example, here is where you would use this function:

```
<?php
   $x=[0.000455,0.000123,0.00005690330203];
   $fname='test.txt';
   $str='';
   foreach($x as $elem){
      $str .= number_format($elem, 5) . "\n";
   }
   file_put_contents($fname,$str);
?>
```

As described in the other answer, float values are inherently imprecise. You have to decide what precision is important to you in your use case.

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Comment: I want to print them into files, not echo $var

Comment: and sometimes 10 is a bit big but sometimes, 10 is a bit small, it is variable.

Answer (score 0):

You should note that there is no such thing as "original form", as the float literal is already a different thing than the internal representation. Floats are by nature imprecise in the context of programming, and a lot of float numbers don't have a specific form that can be represented in decimal. This is why the best you can do is to set some kind of precision on them, like shown in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13252673/365237).

That is not related to PHP but to programming in general.

If you have the same things stored as strings and not as floats, say:

```
$x     = ['0.000455', '0.000123', '0.00005690330203'];
$fname = 'test.txt';
$str   = '';

foreach($x as $elem) {
  $str .= "$elem\n";
}

file_put_contents($fname, $str);
```

then you should have no issues in printing or writing them to a file.

Comment: so how to convert them into strings, there are integers, floating numbers in an array with variable length

Comment: @user1769686 number_format() shown in the other answer does just that, convert it to a string. My point is that if you need an "original form", they should be strings to begin with. If you have the originals as floats, there is no original (base-10) form, and you have to choose yourself what you want to represent. You've already lost your original form and there is no exact way to get it back: you can only guess. The "10" in the other answer is that kind of a guess.